# curl into xml instead of webpage

Tags: php, xml, curl

ok so i am using the following code to set and retrieve the curl url

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $xml_response;
```

my problem is that the api that i am calling has the data in xml format so curl is returning the data in one big string like this

509f0e1f-b8d4-4cb8-b4f0-109751dca4eb0.0114370000000000TrueASIN0273702440SmallAll0273702440http://www.amazon.com/Accounting-Finance-Non-Specialists-Peter-....(ect)

how to have curl display the data in xml format?

Comment: Your browser is displaying the xml like one big string because if it encounters unknown tags, it simply displays the text in them. If you look at in in an inspector you will see the xml tags.

Comment: what is that and can you provide more detail/be more specific?

Comment: ok i believe the problem is solved, i added this before the echo  header('Content-type: application/xml');